# Strange behavior by SikuliX match preview

Tags: sikuli-ide

I am writing a Sikuli script in SikulX and all the images are stored in the default location. However when I tried the preview match function I get the following error messages in the IDE

[error] ImagePath: find: File does not exist: S:\Sikuli%20Scripts\tuning.sikuli\1695241552496.png
[error] PatternPaneTargetOffset: Can't load S:\Sikuli%20Scripts\tuning.sikuli\1695241552496.png
[error] ImagePath: find: File does not exist: S:\Sikuli%20Scripts\tuning.sikuli\1695241552496.png

Even though the images are a screen  capture using the IDE, SikuliX can't find them. I have tried printing out the image path and it seems to be correct The images are in the directory pointed at by the image path.

'The image path is ', [u'S:\Sikuli Scripts\tuning.sikuli'

Now this is the path shown by the IDE, the extra backslashes are added by it.

Now my question is why can sikuliX not find the images?

I tried giving the literal path to the images and was expecting to see the preview pane highlight that part of the region which contains the image. This is on Windows 10 64 bit build 19045.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> S:\Sikuli Scripts\tuning.sikuli

The path should not have intervening blanks (best: only digit/letter/hyphen/underscore)

RaiMan from SikuliX